# Calculate the median date based on two grouping conditions

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, median, summarize

I have the following data frame:

```
> head(df)
# A tibble: 6 x 6
# Groups:   lat, decade [2]
    lat  long date       year  decade    month_day
  <dbl> <dbl> <date>     <chr> <chr>     <chr>    
1    55    18 1952-02-03 1952  1950-1959 02-03    
2    55    18 1958-02-08 1958  1950-1959 02-08    
3    55    18 1958-02-08 1958  1950-1959 02-08    
4    55    18 1958-02-08 1958  1950-1959 02-08    
5    55    18 1965-02-07 1965  1960-1969 02-07    
6    55    18 1966-03-03 1966  1960-1969 03-03    
   


> summary(df)
          lat             long         date                year              decade         
     Min.   :55.00   Min.   :18   Min.   :1951-03-22   Length:1414        Length:1414       
     1st Qu.:56.00   1st Qu.:18   1st Qu.:1987-01-01   Class :character   Class :character  
     Median :58.00   Median :18   Median :2004-04-02   Mode  :character   Mode  :character  
     Mean   :59.07   Mean   :18   Mean   :1999-02-16                                        
     3rd Qu.:62.00   3rd Qu.:18   3rd Qu.:2014-01-01                                        
     Max.   :68.00   Max.   :18   Max.   :2021-03-28                                        
      month_day        
     Length:1414       
     Class :character  
     Mode  :character
```

I would like to get the median `month_day` by degree of latitude (`lat`) **and** per `decade`

I have tried this but cannot get past an error:

```
df = df %>%
  group_by(lat, decade) %>%
  summarise(across(month_day, median)) %>%
  ungroup

Error in `summarise()`:
! Problem while computing `..1 = across(month_day, median)`.
Caused by error:
! `month_day` must return compatible vectors across groups.
i Result type for group 1 (lat = 55, decade = "1950-1959"): <double>.
i Result type for group 2 (lat = 55, decade = "1960-1969"): <character>.
```

I do not know how to solve it, thank you very much for your help.

EDIT:

```
> ds_filtered_median[ds_filtered_median$lat == '57', ]
# A tibble: 124 x 6
     lat  long date       year  decade    month_day
   <dbl> <dbl> <date>     <chr> <chr>     <chr>    
 1    57    18 1955-04-08 1955  1950-1959 04-08    
 2    57    18 1957-02-19 1957  1950-1959 02-19    
 3    57    18 1958-04-06 1958  1950-1959 04-06    
 4    57    18 1959-01-01 1959  1950-1959 01-01    
 5    57    18 1960-01-03 1960  1960-1969 01-03    
 6    57    18 1961-01-02 1961  1960-1969 01-02    
 7    57    18 1962-01-02 1962  1960-1969 01-02    
 8    57    18 1963-01-01 1963  1960-1969 01-01    
 9    57    18 1964-01-19 1964  1960-1969 01-19    
10    57    18 1965-01-12 1965  1960-1969 01-12    
# ... with 114 more rows
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is convert your date to days since the start of a year. From that number you can easily calculate your median. Then convert your days back with any first of january as a reference. You can me one of on leap years though... For date manipulation I used lubridate.

```
library(lubridate)

data %>%
  mutate(
    date = ymd(date),
    days_since_january = as.numeric(date - ymd(paste(year(date), 1, 1, sep = "-")))
  ) %>%
  group_by(lat, decade) %>%
  summarise(across(days_since_january, median), .groups = "keep") %>%
  mutate(median_month_date = format(ymd("1960-01-01") + days(floor(days_since_january)), "%m-%d"))


# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups:   lat, decade [2]
    lat decade    days_since_january median_month_date
  <dbl> <chr>                  <dbl> <chr>            
1    55 1950-1959                 38 02-08            
2    55 1960-1969                 49 02-19  

# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups:   lat, decade [2]
    lat decade    days_since_january median_month_date
  <int> <chr>                  <dbl> <chr>            
1    57 1950-1959               72   03-13            
2    57 1960-1969                1.5 01-02
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it seems to match what I am looking for! I still get this error though while running it: `summarise() has grouped output by 'lat'. You can override using the .groups argument.
Error in mutate():
! Problem while computing median_month_date = format(ymd("1960-01-01") +
  days(days_in_year), "%m-%d").
i The error occurred in group 3: lat = 57.
Caused by error in validObject():
! invalid class “Period” object: periods must have integer values`

Comment: You can avoid the dplyr warning by using `summarise(across(days_in_year, median), .groups = "keep")`. I am not sure how your full data looks like to reproduce your last error, it seems to happen on lat = 57 which is out of the test sample data. I assume you have lubridate package loaded and have no missing data?

Comment: No missing data and no NA's either, I have loaded lubridate. I will edit my post and put all data up to lat = 57

Comment: sorry I do not know how to share the entire data set, I have put the head of the lat = 57. I have checked also: `> sum(is.na(df))
[1] 0` and `> sum(!complete.cases(df))
[1] 0`

Comment: I forgot to take into account that the median can be not an integer, the median of the 1960-1969 of 57 does not give an integer, but a median of 1.5 for these values "median(2,1,1,0,18,11)". I updated my answer and added floor() to the days to be added

Comment: Oh I see I forgot it too, indeed! Now it is working fine, just one more question, I am losing the date column in the process, which I would like to keep for plotting later on, is there a way to keep it? I am not very familiar with the mutate function, I believe it has something to do with it.

Comment: You can use mutate to create your summary table, this of course has no date anymore as for the decade group you have several dates. You can still create a table with all records and group medians using mutate. Try this instead of the summarize row. `mutate(days_since_january = median(days_since_january)) %>%`

Comment: 1 last question: what is doing "days_since_january"? I was looking at the data, and for the date 1952-02-03 (3rd february) "days_since_january" gives 38. Should not it be 34?

Comment: Where you look at the median values or the step prior to it, 2-3 gives 33 days since 1st of january and 2-8 gives 38 days since january, but if you wanted to show the medians of the groups also on your whole data (including the date column), the grouped medians won't change.

Answer (score 0):

You must convert `month_day` to numeric to get the median. `across` is only needed if something is calculated for multiple columns individually e.g. to get median `lon` and `lat` using `data %>% summarise(across(any_of(c("lat", "long")), median))`

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <- tribble(
  ~lat, ~long, ~date, ~year, ~decade, ~month_day,
  55, 18, "1952-02-03", 1952, "1950-1959", "02-03",
  55, 18, "1958-02-08", 1958, "1950-1959", "02-08",
  55, 18, "1958-02-08", 1958, "1950-1959", "02-08",
  55, 18, "1958-02-08", 1958, "1950-1959", "02-08",
  55, 18, "1965-02-07", 1965, "1960-1969", "02-07",
  55, 18, "1966-03-03", 1966, "1960-1969", "03-03"
)

data %>%
  mutate(
    month_day_num = month_day %>% str_extract("[0-9]+$") %>% as.numeric()
  ) %>%
  group_by(lat, decade) %>%
  summarise(
    median_month_day = median(month_day_num)
  )
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'lat'. You can override using the `.groups`
#> argument.
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#> # Groups:   lat [1]
#>     lat decade    median_month_day
#>   <dbl> <chr>                <dbl>
#> 1    55 1950-1959                8
#> 2    55 1960-1969                5
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: I don't fully understand, because the output `median_month_day` is not giving a "month-day" information? Also, I don't understand this part: `str_extract("[0-9]+$")`

Comment: `median`  requires a number e.g. `3` but `"02-03"` is of class character. Either extract the day using regular expression `"[0-9]+$"` or separate day and month into two separate columns. Column `month_day` is not atomic and should be normalized.

Comment: I will try to reformulate. When I do this: `> median(df$date)
[1] "2004-04-02"`, with the column "date" of my df, I get a median date. The output I would like to get is the same style, except that it would be grouped by latitude and decade, which will constraint the output to give me a "month%-day%" answer (instead of "Y%-m%-d%")